# How to check if all columns of a pandas dataframe are equal to a given value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as:

```
x_data  y_data
2.5      2.5
2.5      2.5
2.5      2.5
2.5      2.5
```

How do i know that all values of these columns are equal to 2.5

like if I write: if `all(df==2.5)`

answer should be : 1 1

Answer (score 1):

- The [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) python function, [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), does not allow for selecting an index along which to compare values.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) or a [`Boolean` comparison](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), to determine element-wise equality to a value.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), which will *return whether all elements are `True`, potentially over an axis.*

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_data': [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5], 'y_data': [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5]})

# either implementation can test for equality
df.eq(2.5).all(axis=0)

(df == 2.5).all(axis=0)

# result of either approach
x_data    True
y_data    True
dtype: bool
```